# React Native iOS native module undefined?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I am implementing native interface to access iOS function.

```
//SPRNUtilities.h at /ios/project_name
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
@interface SPRNUtilities : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end

//SPRNUtilities.m
#import "SPRNUtilities.h"
@implementation SPRNUtilities
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(pushNotificationEnabled:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
  id object = nil;
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]){
    object = @(YES);
  }else{
    object = [NSNull null];
  }
  callback(@[object]);
}
```

When I access it on JS code,

```
import { Platform, StyleSheet, NativeModules} from 'react-native';
export default class SPReactNativeUtils{
    static pushNotificationEnabled(callback){
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios'){
            const SPNativeiOS = NativeModules.SPRNUtilities;
            SPNativeiOS.pushNotificationEnabled((enabled) => {
                callback(enabled);
            });
        }else{
            callback(false);
        }
    }
}
```

But got the fail message:

[image]

Could someone help me why I got this problem?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? Currently struggling with that looks like an exactly similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information provided above, please try debugging with following options:

1. In `SPReactNativeUtils.js` line no. 4 put a console log to check if callback is defined
2. check if `SPNativeiOS` is defined - Most like this will you a broader picture if not then go to option 3
3. Put a NSLog in the native code for the value of a. callback b. object at various stages and at last check if value is getting assigned to object
4. Make sure to run `yarn run ios` (create a new build whenever you change the native code)

Hope this helps. If not please provide outputs to the above options to help us debug more :)

Comment: 1. I tried and print log "undefined", That's the problem what I ask.
2. That's the reason why it print the error.
3. xcode module never been called.
4. I have also try "npm start", "react-native run-ios" also. but still not work

Comment: Can you point where is `static pushNotificationEnabled(callback){` getting called from ? Please make sure you pass a valid callback to the function.